# How I can read and write office 365 all documents using java

Tags: java, office365

I am working on one web application and want to read and write excel and word document through JAVA in my application so if any one could use this and having solution then please guide me.

Here 365 store all documents in cloud so I want to read from their could.

Comment: Do you mean you want to access files from OneDrive for Business and SharePoint?

Comment: Yes,Let I give more clarity that Suppose I have purchase Office 365 and save all doc into 365 cloud.Now I want to display this all documents into my web application then how can I ?

Answer (score 0):

- The [Office 365 REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/examples-of-office-365-unified-api-calls#msg_eg_manage_files) can give you access to reading and writing documents hosted in OneDrive for Business.
- Here is a really good explanation on how to use REST web services (in your case O365 APIs) in a Java application. [Learn REST: A Tutorial](http://rest.elkstein.org/)